# got the "Failed to get required buffer size" error message while connect to Kaa server by C SDK

Tags: c, client, kaa

We try to let our endpoint connect to Kaa server by C SDK.
But, we get the error message like below.
It seems the buffer size isn't enough?!
Have any buffer size need to reset for our case??
This message didn't appear before.
But, it seems to appear after we set up a 3 Kaa nodes.

```
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa.c:120] (0) - Kaa SDK version 0.9.0, commit hash 
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:474] (0) - Log collector init completed
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:153] (0) - Kaa client created
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:298] (0) - Starting Kaa client...
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:334] (0) - Channel [0x00000000] Operations error, reinitializing to Bootstrap ...
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_channel_manager.c:215] (0) - Bootstrap transport channel [0x22B2D02C] added (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_platform_protocol.c:252] (0) - Client sync serialized: request id '1', payload size '112'
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_platform_protocol.c:265] (0) - Server sync received: payload size '1076'
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:428] (0) - Received bootstrap server sync: options 0, payload size 1044
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:444] (0) - Received 3 access points (request_id 1)
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:253] (0) - Channel [0x22B2D02C] connection terminated
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_channel_manager.c:298] (0) - Transport channel [0x22B2D02C] was removed
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [posix_kaa_client.c:324] (0) - Channel [0x00000000] Boostrap complete, reinitializing to Operations ...
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [INFO] [kaa_channel_manager.c:215] (0) - Operations transport channel [0xFB3AC3B9] added (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [ERROR] [kaa_platform_protocol.c:156] (-2) - Failed to query extension size for 2
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [ERROR] [kaa_platform_protocol.c:231] (-2) - Failed to get required buffer size
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:1132] (-2) - Kaa TCP channel [0x1DAA5DC5] failed to serialize supported services
2016/11/09 18:38:38 [ERROR] [posix_kaa_client.c:242] (-2) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We found it seems kaa_key.pub is empty.
So, this error message appear.